# Why is this giant water bug out of the water?

Tags: entomology, ethology, limnology

I recently took a picture of a [giant water bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethocerus_americanus) actually out of the water.

[image]

Every instance that I have seen these of critters they have always been in the water (sometimes even feasting on frogs), but this one had climbed up onto a reed.

This could be totally normal behaviour, but it also occurred to me that there are pathogens such as [*Ophiocordyceps unilateralis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiocordyceps_unilateralis) that change insect behaviour, including climbing up blades of grass.

Is climbing up onto reeds a 'normal' or 'aberrant' behaviour for giant water bugs?

Comment: This observation was [identified on iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/110730227) to be an American giant water bug.

Comment: I couldn't find a definitive answer, just a suggestion that they fly to find other ponds and lakes: http://www.naturenorth.com/summer/bug/Giant_Water_Bug.html